# How to use guard-copy (and preserve directory structure)

Tags: ruby, guard

A quick question. I have a directory structure like below.

```
    myroot/
      parent/
        one.png
        two.png
```

I'm trying to copy the .png images to mydestination/ while preserving the parent directory structure of the source.

```
    mydestination/
```

This Guardfile config isn't doing the trick. Is there a way I can get this done?

```
guard :copy, :from => "templ/coffeescript/template/module/", :to => "include", :mkpath => true do
  watch(%r{.+\.png}) do |m| 
    println #{m[0]}
  end 
end
```